# mySQL compare two dates from Year and Week

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

I'm trying to compare two dates to filter my select.

I got this date in db: 2020-W20

Now i'd like to filter out dates older then today (2020-49)

So i tried to remove "-W" from the date in db.

And removed "-" from todays date.

I ended up with (d2)202020 and ($this_y_w)202049.

No in my select:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,1,4), SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,7,2)) as d2 
  FROM table 
 WHERE d2 >= '$this_y_w' 
 ORDER 
    BY delivery_year_week ASC
```

But this doesn't work.

So how should i build my query to select "delivery_year_week" (2020-W20 or 202020) that is bigger or equal to "$this_y_w"(2020-49 or 202049) ?

Comment: Not with you 'select "delivery_year_week" (2020-W20 or 202020) that is bigger or equal to "$this_y_w"(2020-49 or 202049) ' is never going to be true

Comment: @P.Salmon of corse not. But "delivery_year_week" has dates bigger than 2020-49. It was just an example date. (2020-20). How ever i solved it by copy the concat part.. and replace it with d2 in WHERE clause

Comment: @P.Salmon i already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by copy the CONCAT part into d2 in WHERE clause.

```
$query = "SELECT obj_house_floor, CONCAT(SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,1,4), SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,7,2)) as d2 FROM object_house_floor WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,1,4), SUBSTR(delivery_year_week,7,2)) >= '$this_y_w' ORDER BY delivery_year_week ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily remove the `-W` with just `REPLACE(delivery_year_week,'-W','')`.

You can't refer to select field aliases like your `d2` in your where condition; select fields are only calculated *after* rows are filtered by the WHERE clause.

You *can* use them in a HAVING clause (which is applied later in the process), but in this case that would be less efficient than just repeating the expression for d2 in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting the input string to a format that is consistent with the stored values rather than proceeding the other way around:

```
where delivery_year_week >= concat(left(:this_y_w, 4), '-W', right(:this_y_w, 2))
```

Filtering directly on the stored value is much more efficient: it can take advantage of an index on the column, while the other approach cannot, and requires converting the entire column before the filtering can happen. One say that the direct filtering is a SARGable predicate.

Note that I changed the code so it uses a proper query parameter (`:this_y_w`) rather than concatenating variables in the query string.

Finally: if your purpose is to filter against the *current week*, there is no need to use a parameter. It is simpler to do the computation directly in the database:

```
where delivery_year_week > date_format(current_date, '%Y-W%v')
```